# Cannot launch visual studio 2015 community

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015

Sorry if this is in the wrong forum but im not sure where else to post this. After I installed VS 2015 community I encountered this strange error where every time I launch it, it would first show the usual icon then it wont load. I will do a reinstall if the community here isn't able to offer any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: update the graphic card driver. VS uses WPF which uses DirectX to draw the window, so maybe you have a driver issue

Comment: Reinstall would be quickest and easiest to try, if not ask on superuser.com